# Retrieving data from an HTTPS API endpoint using JQuery $.ajax

Tags: jquery

Just getting started with JQuery here; please pardon what I'm sure are terrible questions.

I'm trying to grab some info from an HTTPS API endpoint using the JQuery $.ajax API.

My API is definitely functioning....it conveniently also accepts standard GET requests, so it's pretty easy to see the data that I want to get in my JavaScript.

Ignoring the HTTPS auth for a second (that should be pretty easily handled with the ajax settings or ajaxSetup though from what I understand), when I issue a browser request of the form:
`https://192.168.155.200/json-rpc/1.0?method=GetCompleteStats`

I get a bunch of JSON text spewed back at me in the browser with various info as a result. I'd like to have this formatted as just HTML or plain text for the moment and throw it right in the browser....this is just a proof-of-concept for the moment while I get my legs.

I've stepped through a few tutorials that resulted in functioning demos, although I can't seem to iron this one out. My code does....nothing at the moment. I'd like it to issue an AJAX POST request to the API endpoint when the button is pressed (only one button on the page) and just throw the results into a paragraph tag in a div selector.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>lolsfajaxclient</title>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
      $.ajaxSetup({
        url: "https://192.168.155.200/json-rpc/1.0",
        type: "POST",
        username: "admin",
        password: "lolpassword"
      });

      $("#post").click(function(){
        var completestats = $.ajax({
          data: {method: "getCompleteStats"},
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(data) {
            $("#quote p").html(data);
            alert('Load was performed.');
          }

        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="submit" id="post" value="ajaxin that shit"><br><br>
    <div id="result"><p></p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and

Comment: Also - aware that I should be checking for document ready before I start manipulating page objects....that shouldn't just break everything though..right?

Comment: is API returning `JSONP` ??, if not you have a cross domain problem. If JSONP returned is need to change dataType in $.ajax and parse JSON that is returned into html within ajax success so would need to see json and html structures

Answer (score -1):

You need to do two things here,

Put this function call  on document.onready even to ensure that the document is ready before you try to push the html to the div.

Next thing is, how you are replying to the ajax call. You might not be able to pass plan html using the ajax request properly. Try sending the data as an xml and encapsulate the HTML part of it in [CDATA] enclosures to make sure that it is not mangled in transit. To achieve this, make data type as xml.

It should be a pretty easy task though.

Comment: suggesting that html can't be passed via ajax is absurd